# Turning a word into stars (*)

Tags: php, cpu-word

I am looking for a way to turn a word into stars *. This may be used to show a password, without actually showing the characters or numbers.

The Outcome `$word = "hello";`

```
$newword = "*****";
```

Comment: step 1: count the `N` characters of your `$word`. step 2: write `N` asterisks in your `$newword`. Where you've problem with this task?

Comment: Trying to show the users password in account settings without actually showing it @Federico

Comment: This may be helpful. stackoverflow.com/questions/6175410/… – Karen just now
\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the below code.

```
$word = str_repeat("*", strlen($word));
```

How it work
`str_repeat` has two arguments

1. input : The string to be repeated.
2. multiplier : Number of time the input string should be repeated.

So first we calculated the string length by `strlen` function which work as `multiplier` i.e second argument of function `str_repeat`.

For more [information](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php)